# adding 'use_frameworks!' in podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods, codenameone

How to add this hint `use_frameworks!` in Codename One propertie's build hint?

Anyone can help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set the  `ios.pods.use_frameworks!` build hint to `true`